# Python returning module error when running script, but its listed as installed when I look at modules list

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to call a script from the command line, but python keeps giving me a module error saying it can't find a certain module in the script. I looked at the module list with pip -list, and i saw it listed as an installed module. I don't understand why it's giving me this error. I tried calling the script with both python & python3 commands to see if maybe it was just mixing up the versions(its done this in the past & that solved it), but it still gives me the same result

```html
C:\Users\me\Documents\website scritp\scripts>python3.10 image_viewer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\website scritp\scripts\image_viewer.py", line 8, in <module>
    from Pillow import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pillow'


C:\Users\me>pip list
Package            Version
------------------ -----------
anyio              3.6.2
async-generator    1.10
attrs              22.1.0
beautifulsoup4     4.11.1
certifi            2022.12.7
cffi               1.15.1
charset-normalizer 3.0.1
colorama           0.4.6
decorator          4.0.11
exceptiongroup     1.0.4
h11                0.12.0
httpcore           0.15.0
httpx              0.23.0
idna               3.4
imageio            2.1.2
InstagramAPI       1.0.2
install            1.3.5
moviepy            0.2.3.2
numpy              1.24.2
oauthlib           3.2.2
outcome            1.2.0
Pillow             9.4.0  -HERE
pip                23.0.1
praw               7.6.1
prawcore           2.3.0
proxy-scraper      1.8
pycparser          2.21
pypandoc           1.10
PySimpleGUI        4.60.4
PySocks            1.7.1
pystyle            2.9
pywin32            305
requests           2.28.2
requests-oauthlib  1.3.1
requests-toolbelt  0.7.0
rfc3986            1.5.0
selenium           4.7.2
sklearn            0.0.post1
sniffio            1.3.0
sortedcontainers   2.4.0
soupsieve          2.3.2.post1
tqdm               4.11.2
trio               0.22.0
trio-websocket     0.9.2
tweepy             4.12.1
update-checker     0.18.0
urllib3            1.26.13
websocket-client   1.5.1
wsproto            1.2.0

C:\Users\me>pip3 list
Package            Version
------------------ -----------
anyio              3.6.2
async-generator    1.10
attrs              22.1.0
beautifulsoup4     4.11.1
certifi            2022.12.7
cffi               1.15.1
charset-normalizer 3.0.1
colorama           0.4.6
decorator          4.0.11
exceptiongroup     1.0.4
h11                0.12.0
httpcore           0.15.0
httpx              0.23.0
idna               3.4
imageio            2.1.2
InstagramAPI       1.0.2
install            1.3.5
moviepy            0.2.3.2
numpy              1.24.2
oauthlib           3.2.2
outcome            1.2.0
Pillow             9.4.0  -HERE
pip                23.0.1
praw               7.6.1
prawcore           2.3.0
proxy-scraper      1.8
pycparser          2.21
pypandoc           1.10
PySimpleGUI        4.60.4
PySocks            1.7.1
pystyle            2.9
pywin32            305
requests           2.28.2
requests-oauthlib  1.3.1
requests-toolbelt  0.7.0
rfc3986            1.5.0
selenium           4.7.2
sklearn            0.0.post1
sniffio            1.3.0
sortedcontainers   2.4.0
soupsieve          2.3.2.post1
tqdm               4.11.2
trio               0.22.0
trio-websocket     0.9.2
tweepy             4.12.1
update-checker     0.18.0
urllib3            1.26.13
websocket-client   1.5.1
wsproto            1.2.0
```

```html
also the output for my python version on command prompt

C:\Users\me\Documents\website scritp\scripts>python
Python 3.10.10 (tags/v3.10.10:aad5f6a, Feb  7 2023, 17:20:36) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

why has python stopped registering modules I install all of a sudden? It's also giving me this same error with any other new modules I install(shows them listed, but python can't find them). This only started happening today after I updated my python btw, so maybe its because of that?

Comment: Install library `pillow` and used as `PIL` when import, like `from PIL import Image`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ModuleNotFoundError+%22No+module+named+Pillow%22

Answer (score 1):

Its Called PIL not pillow:

```
from PIL import Image
```

read more at: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html

Answer (score -1):

It's possible you're using the pip from a different installation. To guarantee that you're using the same pip and python, run pip as a module:

```bash
python3.10 -m pip list
```